# Random css showing up on all pages I visit

Tags: html, css, virus

I may be the first but I've seen a lot these style tags on all the pages I visit. I'm thinking it's a virus but I used two Antivirus software and the Windows Defender Offline but those didn't pick up any viruses. Any ideas?

```
<style>a[href^="https://track.restricted.com/"],restricted,[href^="https://restricted.com/"] > img,a[href^="https://restricted.me/"],a[href^="https://track.restricted.com/"],restricted,[href^="https://restricted.com/"] > img,a[href^="https://restricted.me/"]
```

Comment: yes, is not normal. I also use some extensions on chrome, they add some code to every website. try use "incognito mode" one time, open devtools, and see if there is that code you show before

Comment: if in incognito mode there is, then is in theory a virus, because extensions can't be working in incognito. if there isn't that code in incognito you are safe on your pc, maybe is an extension, so delete all extensions and debug. then reinstall only the safest useful ones

Comment: but CSS isn't dangerous as much, javascript scripts are... try see if they add some script to the pages. so my suggestion is delete the extensions

Comment: @LaaouatniAnas The CSS still occurs in Incognito Mode. I have uninstalled and reinstalled Google Chrome but nothing has helped. I've used Windows Sandbox and no unknown CSS is shown there. I'm thinking it's a Virus but no AntiVirus software can pick up on it. Is there any extensions that can track what is added to a page after it's loaded?

Comment: Only issue is that I already have tried to Google the issue. I can't find anything that remotely relates to the issue I have. I have tried to contact people on different forums about it, all the answers resolve to getting an AntiVirus software to remove it which hasn't worked. I'm going to go some more investigating on this issue to see if I can get a resolution, if I get anything I'm probably going to write an article on it to help others if they have the issue as well. Last case scenario I do a full wipe of the OS. Thanks for your help anyways!

Comment: good job! if nothing solve this, try install **firefox** and use that browser instead (make sure that firefox don't have that CSS you show before) --- firefox is famous for the security and privacy, if firefox give you the same behaviour, then you can post a issue on their GitHub repo since firefox is open-source. you will definitely find some experienced programmers that will solve the problem in the next releases(versions). good investigations, we hope you solve that problem soon :)

Comment: Yeah same issue on Firefox

Comment: @LaaouatniAnas Well this is new... so I've reinstalled Windows and it's still showing up on websites. I honestly have no idea what's causing this now. I did a reinstall and wiped everything and went to a new drive.

Comment: Oh, I'm dumb. I found the issue that has been causing this. So Nord VPN has released a new feature which is the Thread Protection. As soon as I turned it off, the code disappeared.

Answer (score 1):

There is no one-size-fits-all answer to this question, as the best way to remove unwanted CSS depends on the specifics of the situation. However, some potential methods include using a browser extension or plugin to block the unwanted CSS, or editing the source code of the pages to remove the CSS manually.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33011863)